Bind an argument to a specific member of a discriminated union
I'm trying to write a function which arguments are based on the properties of a discriminated union, but where they're bound to a single specific member of that union.
type BaseAction = {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
};

type ActionA = BaseAction & { kind: 'a'; params: Record<string, never> };
type ActionB = BaseAction & { kind: 'b'; params: { baz: string } };

type Action = ActionA | ActionB;

function performAction(actionKind: Action['kind'], params: Action['params']) {
  console.log(actionKind, params);
}

// Good.
performAction('a', {});
performAction('b', { baz: '1234' });

// Compiles even though I don't want it to.
performAction('a', { baz: '1234' });
performAction('b', {});

This doesn't work because actionKind essentially becomes 'a' | 'b' and params becomes Record<string, never> | { baz: string }.
How do I force it so that when actionKind is 'a', params can only be Record<string, never>?
I tried a bunch of approaches from similar questions but I couldn't quite figure out how to approach it.

How to force generic argument to be only one type of an union
Narrowing a return type from a generic, discriminated union in TypeScript
Can Typescript infer the specific sub-type of a tagged union, based on a given tag value?

I tried to use a generic type to force some additional requirements on the arguments but to no avail.
function performAction<T extends Action>(actionKind: T['kind'], params: T['params']) {
  console.log(actionKind, params);
}

This doesn't change what actionKind and params ultimately resolve to. Besides, I'm not sure if using a generic type is the correct play here. In the end, performAction is not supposed to work with just any type, it is specifically meant to work with Action, but with only one specific member of it, as bound by actionKind.
Perhaps I could use Extract and infer to achieve what I want?

I think while writing the question I've figured out how to use Extract to achieve it, but is there a more straightforward way to do this?
type BaseAction = {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
};

type ActionA = BaseAction & { kind: 'a'; params: Record<string, never> };
type ActionB = BaseAction & { kind: 'b'; params: { baz: string } };

type Action = ActionA | ActionB;

function performAction<
  Kind extends Action['kind'],
  Act extends Extract<Action, { kind: Kind }>,
>(actionKind: Kind, params: Act['params']) {
  console.log(actionKind, params);
}

// Good.
performAction('a', {});
performAction('b', { baz: '1234' });

// These calls now result in errors:
performAction('a', { baz: '1234' });
performAction('b', {});


Depending on your definition of "more straightforward," you can use function overloads, like this. But as you add more actions it gets more verbose. Your solution looks good to me (but I'm only a journeyman in TypeScript).

Extract is perfectly reasonable. It's hard to know what you mean by "more straightforward", though.

I suppose what I'd prefer is some kind of syntax or a keyword which meant "Always bind to a single member of a discriminated union". Perhaps what I'm trying to do here is a bit convoluted, since usually when dealing with a discriminated union you'd just pass the whole member instead. But I did run into a situation like in the example a couple of times, so I'm glad I at least figured out how to deal with this.
